# Looking for guidance with leaky foundation

Tags: basement, foundation, leaks

I bought a house which needs a tonne of work. I am looking for some guidance of how best to fix and repair leaks as well as clean up and seal the basement in the house. For some reason there is a hole which may have been created by someone, and I cannot tell if the water is coming from under the foundation, or simply through the walls. After using the sump pump the water slowly fills up the hole again, however it does not overflow unless its raining. There is also a well on this property to provide water. A few images are provided. Thank you [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simple, likely just not easy.

Find the source of the water and eliminate it.  For basements the usual sources are rainwater not being drained away from the foundation walls, or groundwater.

With rainwater, your best bet is to ensure that all of your gutters and downspouts are in correct working order and that the downspouts drain in such a way that the water is carried away from the structure and can safely drain off your property.

Groundwater is more difficult and to fix it properly you need to address the basement drainage and sealing from OUTSIDE.  Chances are this property either doesn't have a perimeter drain or it's failed and the walls are not properly waterproofed.  The usual solution is to excavate around the outside down to the footings and install a perimeter drain and then apply an appropriate sealing system on the outside that allows water to drain to the bottom and also prevents and infiltration into the basement.

The final part is a properly installed sump pit and pump to take care of anything that makes it past the first two lines of defense and also takes care of any groundwater that is coming from under the foundation.

There are no shortcuts if you want this done properly.  From the looks of this the problem has been going on for a long time, perhaps since the property was built.

Comment: ...and **slope** the ground surface **away** from the house for at least 10-12 feet,  in the "rainwater" section. This very basic point is often done wrong (or not fixed after settling undoes it) and can make a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a standard sump pump installation. Very common in northern IL area and no doubt other locations . The ground water will always be there , just more or less depending on rainfall. A neighbor had 3 pumps in his sump because there was so much ground water . The water volume is site specific.